# Facebook Graph request is empty when called from Azure

Tags: azure, facebook-graph-api

We're building a mobile application that uses Facebook login and attempts to show users their friends that are also using the application.

We generate an access token as part of the login process and pass this up to our server hosted in Azure.

When we request the users friends using:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=[access_token]&fields=id%2Cname&limit=5
```

We get the following response on our Azure servers:

```
{"data":[]}
```

However requesting the URL directly from my local browser returns a number of records - regardless of whether I'm logged into Facebook or not.

The Facebook App that the user logged in via is published to live (otherwise they wouldn't be able to log in at all).

The only users that return results when called from within Azure are users configured as testers or developers in the Facebook app - is there a setting I've missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the "Country Restricted" setting was causing the problem - we'd limited this to users in the UK which meant requests from the Azure servers in Dublin where returning empty.

Removing this restriction (or possibly increasing to include Ireland) resolved the issue.

Note that this restriction doesn't impact test users, developers or administrators, all of whom work throughout testing and into release.